# Java Constructor Error: Constructor is defined, not found

Tags: java, class, constructor

Receiving this error to which most results say `Define the constructor, homeboy`.  Any insights into what error I am making because I thought it is defined in my class.  I'm pretty new to java, don't shred me if it's obvious.

```
Error: constructor KServer in class KServer cannot be applied to given types;  
                KServer server = new KServer(port);
   required: no arguments
   found: int
   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

KServer.java

```
public class KServer {
    private int port;

    //isn't this the constructor defined?
    public void KServer(int PORT) {
        port = PORT;
    }
    public void Run() {...}
}
```

KServ.java

```
public class KServ {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length != 1) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java KServ <port number>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    KServer server = new KServer(port);
    server.Run();

    }

}
```

Comment: Remove the `void` keyword from your "constructor"

Comment: it had to be a noob mistake.  Shit.  doesn't it technically return void?

Comment: a constructor has no return type - so I guess your "constructor" is interpreted as method

Comment: https://nasvel.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/rules-for-java-constructor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No return type for a constructor, otherwise you define a method.

```
public KServer(int PORT) {
    port = PORT;
}
```

Comment: You won by a few seconds. Damn ! Upvote for your victory.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the word void from the constructor definition :

```
public KServer(int PORT) {
    port = PORT;
}
```

For more details on how to write constructors you can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).

Comment: JP won the race, I'll accept his answer, but you still get an upvote for being cool ;)

Comment: @Chemistpp Lol. Yeah.